# Perform Segue after clicking on search result

Tags: search, core-data, detailsview

I try to to perform a segue to a subclass called "Detail Student" by clicking on the corresponding search result. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. 
I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Here is my code so far:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{student = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", student.vorname, student.name];
cell.textLabel.text = fullname;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = student.hatBetrGrund.name;
    DetailStudent *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier :@"DetailStudent"];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   self.selectedStudent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    controller.student = self.selectedStudent;
    NSLog(@"Wow");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that are not clear in your code:

First, you are setting the text of text and detail labels. This belongs into `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or some other method like `configureCell`. However, selecting from a table view is caught via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Make sure you configure your cell in one method and react to selection in another.

Second, you are instantiating your view controller but not presenting it. You can either

- instantiate the view controller and present it via `presentViewController:animated:` or
- link the detail view controller via a segue in storyboard. In this case, you do not need to instantiate it but simply call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. You configure your detail view in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Hello Mundi, thank you very much vor your reply. I tried to follow your instructions, but I was not able to resolve my problem. I already have created a Segue Called "Detail Student Segue"

Comment: but I cannot performSegueWithIdentifier from the method above. 
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail Student Segue" sender:fullname];`
The app crashes due to "reason: 'Receiver (<Studenten: 0x8a9b880>) has no segue with identifier 'Detail Student Segue"

Comment: `else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail Student Seque"])
    {
        
        DetailStudent *detailStudent = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailStudent.delegate = self;
        detailStudent.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        self.selectedStudent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        
        detailStudent.student = self.selectedStudent;
    }`

Comment: now it worked! I cleaned my project and it worked with performSegueWithIdentifier. Cheers m8!

Comment: I really would love to upvote ur comment, but I'm afraid I have not enough rep for that, this is my first post, just opened the account 28 day ago, but I will do so as soon as I am allowed to

Comment: You should be able to tick the checkmark below the up-vote number.