# Empty Detail View is presented when clicking on search results

Tags: uitableview, search, core-data

I have a problem. I have created a Table View in which students are listed. By clicking on the corresponding student, the corresponding detail view appears. Now I implemented a search bar with search results in my project, but everytime I use the search bar, an empty Detail View shows up (without any chance to select the right search result) I really do not know why.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Student Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    Student *student = nil;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {student = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ (%@)", student.vorname, student.name, student.hatBetrGrund.name];
    cell.textLabel.text = fullname;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail Student Seque" sender:student.name]; // if search results are found
    }
    else
    {
    student =[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", student.vorname, student.name];
    cell.textLabel.text = fullname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = student.hatBetrGrund.name;
    }

   return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Student Segue"])
    {

        AddStudent *addStudent = segue.destinationViewController;
        addStudent.delegate = self;
        addStudent.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail Student Seque"])
    {
        DetailStudent *detailStudent = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailStudent.delegate = self;
        detailStudent.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        self.selectedStudent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        detailStudent.student = self.selectedStudent;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"wow, such Fail!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20785098/427083).

Comment: @Mundi Right. Marvin, stick with a single answer since the following looks like the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks very strange to me. Why are performing the segue within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? It's not the right place to do it. This delegate should be used to take into account the display of content.

The method you should use to perform the segue is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. When you click a row, then you can just grab the specified user (from the plain content or the filtered one) and perform the segue.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // grab the user from the filtered results
    } else {
        // grab the user from the plain results
    }

    // perform the segue here (I guess in both cases you need to display details of the user)
}
```

Note that these are just hints...

Comment: wow, thank you very much. I finally did it. Unfortunately i cannot upvote your answer due to low rep.

Comment: I did it like this:
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail Student Seque" sender:self];
    } else {NSLog(@"wow");}

}`

Comment: @Marvin If my answer helped you, you could also mark at answered. As you prefer. Cheers.

Comment: I really would love to upvote ur comment, but I'm afraid I have not enough rep for that, this is my first post, just opened the account 28 day ago, but I will do so as soon as I am allowed to

Comment: @Marvin Near each question there is a checkmark. You can click on it and it will become green.

Comment: @Marvin You could also take a tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour. In addition, if you previously made other questions and the answerer replied correctly, you can do the same. Your reputation will grow.